# How to assign data from viewController to tableViewCell labels?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have viewController with tableView, tableView has two prototype cells, second cell has sno, date, amount 3 labels. I created TableViewCell class and i created 3 outlets for this 3 labels in this TableViewCell class. I am getting data from server and i want to assign that data to this 3 labels. How?

In tableViewCell.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *serialNumber;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *amountLabel;
```

In viewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.displayDataTableView.delegate = self;
self.displayDataTableView.dataSource = self;

self.urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
self.urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://"]];
self.dataTask = [self.urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:self.urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSMutableDictionary *serverRes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    //        NSLog(@"...%@ ", serverRes);

    self.integer = [[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] count];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.displayDataTableView reloadData];
    });

self.dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[self.dateArray addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Date"]];
[self.amountArray addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"TotalAmount"]];

}


}];

[self.dataTask resume];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}else{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailsTitle" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   TableViewCell *tvc;
    tvc.dateLabel.text = [self.dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"********** = %@", tvc.dateLabel.text);

    return cell;


}

}
```

Comment: I imported tableViewCell .h in viewController and i assigned  TableViewCell *tvc;
    tvc.dateLabel.text = [self.dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"********** = %@", tvc.dateLabel.text);   but i showing null

Comment: yes, it's value is NULL, it's not printing any data in tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.displayDataTableView reloadData];
});

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
 if(indexPath.row == 0)
{

 static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"detailsCell";
// Make Your cell as this
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier]; 
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

 }
 cell.dateLabel.text = [self.dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.amountLabel.text = [self.amountArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
return cell; 
}
```

Comment: Where is CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) Please make your cell your problem will be resolve If you make custom cell than make as this

Answer (score 0):

you need to change class of tableview cell

else{

```
 TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailsTitle" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.dateLabel.text = [self.dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// same 
  cell.amountLabel.text = [self.dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"********** = %@", cell.dateLabel.text);

    return cell;
```

}

or change sequence

```
self.dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[self.dateArray addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Date"]];
[self.amountArray addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"TotalAmount"]];

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.displayDataTableView reloadData];
    });
```

Comment: cell.dateLabel.text = [self.dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  TableViewCell *tvc;
    tvc.dateLabel.text = [self.dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 but dateLabel present in tebleViewCell

Comment: yes but what you want to do ? use different class ?

Comment: i am using different class i.e; tableViewCell this class has properties sno, dateLabel and amountLabel

Comment: then change that class with my class .

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
self.dataTask = [self.urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:self.urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            NSMutableDictionary *serverRes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

        self.dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         for (int i = 0; i < [[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] count]; i++) {
                    [self.dateArray addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Date"]];
                    [self.amountArray addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"Data"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"TotalAmount"]];
                }

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.displayDataTableView reloadData];
            });

        }];
```